# Looking for errors in a React component export/import

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webpack, babeljs, require

I'm new to the React stack, trying to build a library of simple shared components.  The components work fine in their home project.  I've configured them using [this](https://medium.com/@lokhmakov/best-way-to-create-npm-packages-with-create-react-app-b24dd449c354) advice.  Dropped them into a local git, npm installed them a new project with git+https.  The components show up in the new project /node_modules/.../lib, as expected.

When the following runs, I end up with undefined exports:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.NeonFooter = exports.default = undefined;

var _NeonFooter = require('./components/NeonFooter');
var _NeonMenu = require('./components/NeonMenu');

exports.default = _NeonMenu.NeonMenu;
exports.NeonFooter = _NeonFooter.NeonFooter;
```

Dropping into chrome's debugger and using some console statements, (for instance) _NeonFooter does show up as an _esModule, with a correctly pathed closure to the NeonFooter.js file in scope.  No direct _NeonFooter.NeonFooter field, though.  When _NeonFooter.NeonFooter is referenced it comes up undefined.

I can't seem to get the vscode debugger or chrome to bind to a breakpoint on the require, and there's no exception occurring to break on.  How do I dig into this further to find the actual error that leads to the undefined value?

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger; keyword in the source?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful.  It looks like my module is being loaded into the installedModules cache, but the exports aren't being populated.  That should be enough to go on.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like the issue is with a Babel transformation, or with how that transformation is being consumed by React. Changing the transformed code to

```
exports.NeonMenu = _NeonMenu.default;
exports.NeonFooter = _NeonFooter.default;
```

solves the issue.

Still trying to determine the correct Babel/React behavior, but it's a step forward.